# VScode shortcut to open new file and edit its name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw my course instructor do this, and i would like to know if there is a shortcut already existing or if there is a keybinding i can set.

What i want is, when i am currently editing a file for example, i am in ~/src/components/dashboard/dashboard.js and i press the shortcut and it takes me to the file explorer where i will be allowed to name the new file in the same directory, ie ~/src/components/dashboard/

[image: before clicking the shortcut]

[image: after clicking the shortcut]

I basically want the functionality we get when we click on the folder that we want a new file in, and then click the new File icon

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as trivial as just invoking the `"explorer.newFile"` command; it has a default binding that only works while the Explorer viewlet has focus; it looks like this on Windows:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+n",
  "command": "explorer.newFile",
  "when": "explorerViewletFocus"
}
```

... so it's a matter of assigning a new shortcut that does the same, but without the `when` clause:

```
{
  "key": "<YOUR SHORTCUT>",
  "command": "explorer.newFile"  
}
```

You can still add the `when` clause that would help if you want to reuse the shortcut (e.g. opening a new terminal while the terminal has focus):

```
{
  "key": "<YOUR SHORTCUT>",
  "command": "explorer.newFile",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

A full reference about the `when` clause can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts